# Find which dependency in pom.xml include the specified jar

Tags: java, maven

There are multiple modules in one web project and the project uses maven to manage the jars. I am curious that how to find which dependency in pom.xml the jar belongs to ? for example.
in ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/xxx.jar

I want to find the dependency A in pom.xml which includes the jar. 
dependency A -> denpendency B -> denpendency xxx (xxx.jar)

Comment: If you use eclipse you can see this information

Comment: have you tried running `mvn -X compile` i think it's in the output

Answer (score 1):

`mvn dependency:tree` will print out a tree of how your dependencies are being resolved.

You can search that output for the jar you are interested in.

*There's probably other ways to work it out, but I tend to just pick a small set of generally useful commands and rely on them for most tasks*